# Why the justify-content property is not working?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am writing a code to practice CSS flexbox properties but whenever I apply the properties, they do not work. The page looks the same with no difference. The browsers that I have used are chrome and microsoft edge. When I am applying the width or flex-basis or justify-content property, it is not implemented in browser

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  /*flex-direction: row; */
}

.container div,
.container2 div {
  /* We are using .container div to apply this border to div elements in the main code */
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 1;
}

.box1 {
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.box2 {
  order: 3;
}

.box3 {
  order: 2;
}

.containers {
  width: 1;
}

.container2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1">
    <h3>Box1</h3>
    <p>Hello to kaisay ho aap log</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
    <h3>Box2</h3>

    <p>Kaisa guzr rha quarantine</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box3">
    <h3>Box3</h3>
    <p>Bs shi chal rha hai sb kuch</p>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="container2">
  <div class="containers">
    <h3>Box5</h3>
    <p>What shall i do</p>
  </div>
  <div class="containers">
    <h3>Box6</h3>
    <p>What shall i do</p>
  </div>
  <div class="containers">
    <h3>Box7</h3>
    <p>What shall i do</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Well you are giving each div an `flex: 1` property, which means it takes al the remaining space. If you have 3 divs with each the `flex: 1` property it will equal to a `width: 33.33%`.  Remove the `flex: 1` in your `.container div, .container2 div` class to see how justify-content works.

Comment: When I tried to learn CSS, I found bootstrap that really helped me to code ! Just by modifying the class of your element, you can change the style! Juste add a line in the header of your html file -> check here : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/ you should take a look at it. It make code easier ! ;) Example for your problem :
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/#justify-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that flexbox is enabled on the parent and that affects the immediate children - but a child can also be made into a flex parent.

So you need to also make the containers containing the text you want to center into flexbox parents:

```
.container div *, .container2 div *{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Or, you could just use `text-align: center` to center the text with those elements.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  /*flex-direction: row; */
}

.container>div,
.container2>div {
  /* We are using .container div to apply this border to div elements in the main code */
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 1;
}

.container div * {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container2 div *{
  text-align: center;
}

.xbox1 {
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.box2 {
  order: 3;
}

.box3 {
  order: 2;
}

.container2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1">
    <h3>Box1</h3>
    <p>Hello to kaisay ho aap log</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
    <h3>Box2</h3>
    <p>Kaisa guzr rha quarantine</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box3">
    <h3>Box3</h3>
    <p>Bs shi chal rha hai sb kuch</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container2">
  <div class="containers">
    <h3>Box5</h3>
    <p>What shall i do</p>
  </div>
  <div class="containers">
    <h3>Box6</h3>
    <p>What shall i do</p>
  </div>
  <div class="containers">
    <h3>Box7</h3>
    <p>What shall i do</p>
  </div>
</div>
```